# Raspberry Pi 400 ubuntu boot

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi

I've been having a few issues with this. I followed the guide here; https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi but it stopped, rather I got a black screen shortly after the ubuntu logo appears. I've tried various things, SDs and USBs alike, but both face the same issue. I'm thinking it might not be an issue with the disk image as it's sourced via raspberry pi installer from the internet, also tried with a manual .iso with the same issue. Is this a ubuntu issue or should I consult raspberry pi people?

The USB lights indicate that it's still being read/written but stays like that for hours with nothing from the pi.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Rory

Comment: If you see the Raspberry PI logo and then it just goes Black it's normally the graphics settings.  See if you can SSH into the Raspberry PI from another machine and check the HDMI/Graphics settings from there.  Try sudo raspi-config

Comment: Actually...  You can't activate SSH until you have logged into the device - I forgot that!!  What I had to do was basically plug the pi into different monitors (my TV worked in the end) until I could log in correctly, I then setup SSH, etc.  My issue was the KMS Driver setting, it had to be disabled.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for your message. I'm new here, with a new pi (Trying to get linux onto it to have as a console for network management), so really appreciate that there's a community where, when you ask a question, someone answers it! I look forward to reciprocating it.